# Do I have to type su every time?

Tags: privileges, accounts

I have created a user.

```
useradd -M -d /usr/my_user my_user 
chown -R my_user. /usr/my_user
```

Now as a root I can type:

```
su - my_user -c /usr/my_user/some_dir/script.sh
```

but if I want to do more complicated things, for example navigate between **my_user** folders I have to type the su - my_user pattern every time. Otherwise it states that I do not have permissions.

How can I make my life easier and not type the `su` every time?

Comment: Why would you create a user and not log in as that user?  Set a password for `my_user` and log in.  Doing everything as root like you suggest is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fully switch context between users you have to provide following command

```
su my_user
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use a `group`.

```
groupadd my_group
usermod -G my_group my_self
usermod -G my_group my_user
chown -R my_user:my_group /usr/my_user
chmod -R g+w /usr/my_user
```

Then you can login as `my_self`and have access to `/usr/my_user` in the same way `my_user` can.